# How to check dash after repeating groups in regex

Tags: regex

Sample string:

```
MON,00:00-10:00-11:00-13:00-15:00-16:00;TUE,00:00-23:59;
```

Regex:

```
^((MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN),(([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])-([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]))+;)+$
```

Here I want to check dash is there (not optional) after every interval of start and end time.

> 00:00-10:00
> 11:00-13:00
> 15:00-16:00

So the above will be

```
00:00-10:00-11:00-13:00-15:00-16:00
```

Comment: `^(?:MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN),((?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):(?:[0-5][0-9])(?:-(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):(?:[0-5][0-9]))+);` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/sZ3FaK/1))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a day, then pairs of time parts with a `-` and optionally repeated with also a `-` in between ending on a `;`

To match that format over the whole line, you can repeat those parts over the whole line.

```
^(?:(?:MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN),(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]-(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](?:-(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]-(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9])*;)+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BrXZvV/1)

Using a capture group to match the pairs of intervals for a single part:

```
^(?:MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN),((?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]-(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](?:-(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]-(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9])*);
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LiR6eQ/1)

Comment: Thank you @The fourth bird. Great, it works!